# Execute a Windows command with a controled environment in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi

I currently trying to execute a command in C++11 under Windows, and I want the environment to be a char** that I manually set.

I saw the popen(), system() and CreateProcess() functions, but I cannot achieve that with theses functions.
What I am looking for is an alternative to the UNIX exec* functions, with allows us to precise environment.

Comment: `CreateProcess` has an argument named `lpEnvironment` to set the child's environement variables. How do you use `CreateProcess` (i.e. show your code) ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Oh my bad, i should have triple check CreateProcess...

Comment: Or _execle() and friends, those unix functions you like work on MSVC as well.

Comment: @HansPassant But you don't have `fork()` so you can't get the behavior of `_popen` or `CreateProcess` with `_exec*`, else you're under Cygwin. But `_spawn*` functions can do it, indeed.

Comment: Be aware that some software won't work properly without the usual set of environment variables.  (Most well written software will.)

Answer (score 3):

You want the `lpEnvironment` parameter of [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425):

> lpEnvironment [in, optional]
>
> A pointer to the environment block for the new process. If this parameter is **NULL**, the new process uses the environment of the calling process.
>
> An environment block consists of a null-terminated block of null-terminated strings. Each string is in the following form:
>
> name=value\0

Example:

```
// example for storing environment variables dynamically
std::map<std::string, std::string> env = { {"name1", "value1"}, {"name2", "value2"} };

// example for generating block of strings
std::vector<char> envBlock;
std::for_each(env.begin(), env.end(),
    [&envBlock](const std::pair<std::string, std::string> & p) {
        std::copy(p.first.begin(), p.first.end(), std::back_inserter(envBlock));
        envBlock.push_back('=');
        std::copy(p.second.begin(), p.second.end(), std::back_inserter(envBlock));
        envBlock.push_back('\0');
    }
);
envBlock.push_back('\0');

// feed this into ::CreateProcess()
LPVOID lpEnvironment = (LPVOID)envBlock.data();
```

Comment: Don't take it wrong, but I just don't understand the point of preferring this over `LPVOID lpEnvironment = "name1=value1\0name2=value2\0";`. Can you explain ?

Comment: @mikedu95 The idea is that you can dynamically change the environment variables you want to define in the vector, then generate the block when required. It's an example snippet; the code that generates the LPVOID block would ideally go in a separate method.

Comment: In that case you've better to use a `map<string, string>`. With the `vector<string>`, I don't see how to easily change the value of variable `"name2"` into `"new_value2"` once the vector has been initialized for example. It's the same pain as with the version I have given.